# Generate a 2D mesh from an outline

Tags: algorithm, geometry, clipping

I got an outline (list of points) for a plane I want to generate. The plane is quite big and I need evenly distributed vertices inside the outline. Each vertex has a color value from red to green to visualize some data in the plane. I need to visualize the data as precise as possible in real time.

My idea was to simply create a grid and adjust all the vertices outside of the outline. This turned out to be quite complex.

This is a quick example what I want to achieve.
[image: Clipping a 2D grid by an outline]

Is there any algorithm that solves this problem?
Is there another way to generate a mesh from an outline with evenly distributed vertices?

Comment: Can specify what you mean by evenly "distributed vertices"? Specifically, why can't you randomly distribute vertices in the outline and perform point set triangulation?

Comment: Each vertex has a color value from red to green that represents some data in the plane. The data can change quite a lot at some points. Therefore randomly distributed vertices could result in a "blind spot" where the color is just interpolated from other vertices and does not show the actual data. Ideally, I could influence the distance between two vertices.

Comment: I don´t understand how you could avoid blind spots. You can can influence the distance between two vertices if you sample more points, right? How is a grid-based approach beneficial to random sampling?

Comment: How about the following approach: You start with a vertex at the centroid of your outline and build a (coarse) mesh. Then as long as you want to continue, you put a centroid at each of the triangles from the previous iteration and split it into three smaller ones.

Comment: Hm that could work for a convex outline. Not an ideal distribution but it could be good enough. The problem is that I neither know the shape nor the size of the outline (the outline is generated by the user). 5 iterations may be overkill for one outline and not enough for another. I will give it a try and see how it looks like.

Comment: It sounds like what you might be after is a **morphing** algorithm that takes the perimeter of the source (the black square grid) and smoothly maps the interior to fit the perimeter of the destination (the red triangle). This can be relatively straightforward when both source and destination have the same number of edges, but for a user-supplied destination you're going to have an interesting time working out which edges go to which...

Comment: Morphing sounds like another option that is just as complicated as clipping the source to the destination.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do something like this:

1) First generate a triangulate your polygon to create a mesh.  There are plenty of options: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation

2) Then while any of the edges in the mesh are too long (meaning that the points at either end might be too far apart), add the midpoint of the longest edge to the mesh, dividing the adjacent triangles into 2.

The results is a mesh with every point within a limited distance of other points in every direction.   The resulting mesh will not necessarily be *optimal*, in that it may have more points than are strictly required, but it will probably satisfy your needs.

If you need to reduce the number of points and thin triangles, you can apply Delaunay Triangulation flipping around each candidate edge first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Visual_Delaunay_definition:_Flipping

Comment: I was reinventing the wheel on this too, and knowing to look for "polygon triangulation" was a lifesaver! I think that this answer (much belated) deserves to be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Although not totally clear from the question, the [marching cubes algorithm](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/), adapted to two dimensions, comes to mind. A detailed descriptione of the two-dimensional version can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares).

Comment: The marching cubes / squares algorithm does not solve the problem as far as I know. I don't really know how to describe the problem in an understandable way.

Answer (score 0):

Delaunay meshing can create evenly distributed vertices inside a shape. The image below shows a combined grid- and Delaunay-mesh. You may have a look [here](http://www.geom.at/advanced-mesh-generation/).

[image: http://www.geom.at/wp-content/uploads/grid-mesh.png]